# Gradle 7: get effective dependency version in a task

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies, gradle-task

I need to have a list of dependencies for each subproject with effective dependency versions. There are some version conflicts for some transitive dependencies and higher version is used. So if I execute `gradle dependencies` I see smth like this:

```
com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:3.0.61 -> 3.1.5
```

So subproject has transitive dependency of version `3.0.61`, but since there is higher version `3.1.5` in the project, it will be used.

I have next task now:

```
task listDependencies() {
    doFirst {
        subprojects {
            it.project.configurations.resolvableImpl.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
                println(it.file.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It lists `3.0.61` version, but it does not exist in the final package. I need to get final effective version in that list somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try below if it helps, you can put it in the main build.gradle (no task needed.

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        println project.name
        project.configurations.findAll {
            print "\t"
            println it.name
            if (["incrementalScalaAnalysisElements", "incrementalScalaAnalysisFormain", "incrementalScalaAnalysisFortest"].contains(it.name)) println "\t\t -- Skipped"
            else if (it.canBeResolved) it.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.findAll {ra -> println "\t\t" + ra.file.name}
            else println "\t\t -- not resolvable"
            //else it.files { nra -> println nra}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,  but it shows same version `3.0.61` :(

Answer (score 0):

Configuration which is working for me:

```
configurations {
    deployable
}

dependencies {
    deployable project(':sub-group:sub-project1')
    deployable project(':sub-group:sub-project2')
    deployable project(':sub-group:sub-project3')
}

task generateLibsDescriptors() {
    dependsOn(configurations.deployable.dependencies.dependencyProject.path.collect { it + ":jar" })
    doFirst {
        configurations.deployable.dependencies.forEach { deployableDependency ->
            println deployableDependency.name
            configurations.deployable.files(deployableDependency).forEach { file ->
                println "\t${file.name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```